# How to handle passing an array or single value to a function

Tags: php

I want to make a function that accepts an array or single value as a parameter (I want `foreach()` to work in two cases)

```
function handle($users)
{
   foreach($users as $user){}    
}
```

So what I'm really want to do is to make the above function works if I pass `handle($users)` as an array of objects or `handle($user)` as a single object

Comment: Test `$users` before you use it :)

Comment: Pass the single user in an array `handle([$user])`. Alternatively, you could use `is_array` inside the function to detect whether you've gotten an array.

Comment: I want `foreach()` to work in two cases, so if I use `handle([$user])` it will convert the array to an array

Comment: @El_Vanja if you meant in your answer that you will use `handle([$user])` this method while passing the single value only so it's a good answer and we will need the check :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test $users before you use it

```
function handle($users)
{
    if (is_array($users)) {
        foreach($users as $user){}    
    }else{
        // its a single object
    }
}
```

or pass the single user in an array anyway.

```
function handle($users)
{
   foreach($users as $user){}    
}

handle([$user]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function handle($users)
{
   if (!is_array($users)) {
      $users = [$users];
   }

   foreach ($users as $user) {}
}
```

Comment: Is making the check in the function better than passing it as an array or not? 
like using this `handle([$user])`

Comment: It's neither better nor worse. Checking in the function just helps to avoid a mistake, when someone will pass __not__ array and get some strange output or even exception.

Comment: But my point is to use type hinting (array) is better I think as I make a restriction to use only arrays in this function.

Comment: Typehint also helps.

Answer (score 0):

use `is_array` to detect

```
function handle($users)
{
   $users = is_array($users) ? $users : [$users];
   foreach($users as $user){}
}
```

Comment: Nice answer bro, but we can make it easier like above answers

Comment: @TheGeeky another way to do it than :)